# Drawing pedigree using madeline2

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, command-line, svg

Have anyone tried to use [madeline2](http://eyegene.ophthy.med.umich.edu/madeline/install.php) to generate a pedigree? I want to use madeline2 to connect directly to mysql to generate an svg file but couldn't. The project website did mention that madeline2 can access to mysql but did not provide any sample. That would be a great help if someone can provide me an example. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have generated a madeline2 pedigree using XML format of the input. I downloaded the application and then started with a test XML and made calls to the application from my terminal.

madeline2 -o [generated-file.svg] [test.xml]